# asp.net custom control attribute dependent on another attribute

Tags: c#, asp.net, user-controls, custom-attributes

Is it possible in asp.net that for a custom control (that extends UserControl) to have attributes that depend on other attributes from the same control.
Ex.
`<control:Custom attr1="value1" attr2="value2"></control:Custom>`
I want to be able to set the `attr2` only if `attr1` isn't, and vice versa ...

I know that for the Java 'equivalent', the tags, you could specify, in the tag descriptor, the attribute's dependencies.

Is there an annotation in asp.net to enforce this kind of behavior?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So i didn't found an attribute class that can be placed on my property, and I went with trowing an exception when setting the property.